# CKEditor Django with TextInput instead of TextArea

Tags: textinput, django-ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor in my Django admin and for example for a specific form I used:

```
class ChoiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    text = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorWidget())
    class Meta:
        model = Choice
        fields = '__all__'
```

With the correct configurations in my settings.py, it works fine.
The problem now is that the text field is a textArea and I would like to have an TextInput instead. 
Before of using CKEditor the field was like this:

```
text=forms.CharField(label='Name', max_length=100,
                               widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': '20'}))
```

How can I make what I need, use CKEditor as a TextInput and with a specific size?